# Suppose $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly for $n \to \infty$. What can we say about $\mu$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ is a metric space and $\mathcal{A}$ the canonical Borel sigma algebra on $X$. Let $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of probability measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and suppose $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly for $n \to \infty$ i.e.
$$
\int_X f d\mu_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_X f d\mu 
$$
for all $f \in C_b(X)$.

- What can we say about $\mu$? Is it a probability measure? A finite measure?

Feel free to link to theorems etc.

Comment: Do you mean weakly or in the weak$^*$ topology?

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ is not the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then it doesn't make much sense to talk about weak convergence (because e.g. continuous functions need not be measurable).

Comment: There are several possible definitions of "weakly".  For most of them the answers to your first questions are contained in the definition.

Comment: I have updated the question in regards to your comments, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided $X$ is a Polish (i.e. complete and separable) metric space, $\mu$ is a probability measure. First, we test against the constant function $1$, explicitly

$$ 1 \equiv \int_X 1\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n \to \int_X 1\,\mathrm{d}\mu =\mu(X)$$

It remains to check that $\mu$ is a positive measure. By Hahn's decomposition theorem, write $X=X_+\cup X_-$ which is a disjoint union, with $\mu(E)\ge0$ for all $E\subseteq X_+$ and $\mu(E)\le0$ for all $E\subseteq X_-$. This means also $\mu=\mu_+-\mu_-$ where $\mu_+,\mu_-$ are the positive measures

$$\mu_\pm(E) := \mu(E\cap X_\pm) $$

Then, for any compact $K\subset X_-$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}_+$, consider the non-negative, bounded continuous function

$$ f_{K,N} := \max\{1-N\,\mathrm{dist}(x,K),0\} $$

By weak convergence,

$$ \int_Xf_{K,N}\,\mathrm{d}\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_{K,N}\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\ge0$$

So

$$\int_Xf_{K,N}\,\mathrm{d}\mu_+ - \int_Xf_{K,N}\,\mathrm{d}\mu_-\ge0$$

Now take $N\to\infty$ and apply dominated convergence theorem,

$$-\mu_-(K) = \mu_+(K) - \mu_-(K) \ge0$$

Since $K$ is an arbitrary subset of $X_-$, by regularity of finite Borel measures on Polish spaces we see that $\mu_-$ is the zero measure. Hence $\mu=\mu_+$ is a positive measure.

Comment: I don't know what duality is and what you mean by "test against", sorry. So it would imply that the space of probability measures is a closed set? Would this also imply that it is compact? Suppose the sequence above is a convergent subsequence instead. I have also updated the question with the definition of weak convergence I am using.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explicitly give the meaning of "test against" (however, it's a very common phrase). Yes, the space $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of probability measures on $X$ is closed, under the weak topology, in the space $\mathcal{M}(X)$ of signed Borel measures on $X$. No, it will not be compact in general: In fact, Prokhorov's theorem says a subset $E\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ is compact iff it is tight. Then it's easy to see that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is compact iff $X$ is compact.